# What does `>:` mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

Done some searching with no success to find what `>:` is. So, let it accompany the remaining "What does ... mean in Scala" questions here :-)

Comment: `A >: B` embodies the same idea as `B <: A`, which is that `B` is a subtype of `A`.

Comment: [Scala FAQ: How do I find what some symbol means or does?](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [lower type bound](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/137).